# Javascript Game with Loop For Crashing Browser

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have created a mini-game in my medieval themed game called Teetotum (based of the historical version) and wrote a script for it that causes the browser to go unresponsive. I assume this is because of my Loop For parts not being able to break out of the loop, but I have checked my code again and again and it all seems to be fine, but having new eyes look at it may help.

So, can anyone tell me why the following crashes my browser? And better yet can anyone tell me how to fix it or make it work?

```
function minigame(game, previous) {
 var minigameDiv = document.getElementById('minigames');
 show('minigames');
 minigameDiv.innerHTML = "<br>";
  if (game == "teetotum") {
   minigameDiv.innerHTML += "Teetotum is a game of chance, commonly played  with 2 or more players. You spin the top, if it falls on 1, then you take 5 Shrill from the pot. If it falls on 2, no action is taken. If it falls on 3, you add 5 Shrill to the pot. Lastly, if it falls on 4, you win the whole pot.<br><br>";
   minigameDiv.innerHTML += "If you would like to play, set the pot below with the amount you want and how many players you want to play with. <br><br><br>"
   minigameDiv.innerHTML += "<select id='potAmount'> <option selected='selected' value='10'>10 Shrill</option> <option value='25'>25 Shrill</option> <option value='50'>50 Shrill</option></select>Pot Amount<br>"
   minigameDiv.innerHTML += "<select id='playerCount'> <option selected='selected' value='2'>2 Players</option> <option value='3'>3 Players</option> <option value='4'>4 Players</option></select>Player Count<br><br>"      
   minigameDiv.innerHTML += "<a class='button' onclick='javascript:Teetotum(\""+previous+"\");'>Confirm Settings & Begin</a> <br> <a class='button' onclick='javascript:show(\""+previous+"\");'>Go Back to the Tavern</a>";
 }
}


function Teetotum(goBack) {
 playerCount = document.getElementById("playerCount").value;
 totalPlayer = 1;
 potAmount = document.getElementById("potAmount").value;
 var minigameDiv = document.getElementById('minigames');
  if (shrillAmount >= potAmount) {
   shrillAmount = shrillAmount - potAmount;
   checkMoney();
    for (; potAmount > 0;) {
     minigameDiv.innerHTML = "You spin the top...";
     var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4); 
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (randomNumber == 1) {
           potAmount = potAmount - 5;
           shrillAmount = shrillAmount + 5;
           minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 1! You take 5 Shrill from the pot. The pot is "+potAmount+"."
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 2) {
           minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 2. Nothing happens. The pot is "+potAmount+"."
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 3 && shrillAmount >= 5) {
           potAmount = potAmount + 5;
           shrillAmount = shrillAmount - 5;
           minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 3! You lose 5 Shrill into the pot. The pot is "+potAmount+"."
        }
        else if (randomNumber == 4) {
           shrillAmount = shrillAmount + potAmount;
           potAmount = potAmount - potAmount;
           minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 4! You win the whole pot."
        }
        if (potAmount > 0) {
           minigameDiv.innerHTML += "<br><br>The next player(s) will now take their turn."
                 setTimeout(function() {
                 for (playerCount = playerCount; playerCount > totalPlayer && potAmount > 0; playerCount--) {
                    minigameDiv.innerHTML = ('Player '+playerCount+' spins the top...');
                    var randomAINumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
                       setTimeout(function() {
                       if (randomAINumber == 1) {
                          potAmount = potAmount - 5;
                          minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 1. Player "+playerCount+" takes 5 Shrill from the pot. The pot is "+potAmount+"."
                       }
                       else if (randomAINumber == 2) {
                          minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 2. Nothing happens. The pot is "+potAmount+"."
                       }
                       else if (randomAINumber == 3) {
                          potAmount = potAmount + 5;
                          minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 3. Player "+playerCount+" puts 5 Shrill into the pot. The pot is "+potAmount+"."
                       }
                       else if (randomAINumber == 4) {
                          shrillAmount = shrillAmount + potAmount;
                          potAmount = potAmount - potAmount;
                          minigameDiv.innerHTML = "It lands on a 4! Player "+playerCount+" wins the pot."
                       }
                       if (potAmount <= 0) {
                          minigameDiv.innerHTML += "<br><br>The game is now finished <br><br><br> <a class='button' onclick='javascript:show(\""+previous+"\");'>Go Back to the Tavern</a>"
                       }
                    }, 2000);
                 }
      }, 3000);
        }
        if (potAmount <= 0) {
           minigameDiv.innerHTML += "<br><br>The game is now finished <br><br><br> <a class='button' onclick='javascript:show(\""+previous+"\");'>Go Back to the Tavern</a>"
        }
      }, 3000);
  }
}
else {
  ui.log('You do not have enough Shrill to do that.');
}
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to try to help, it's much appreciated! :D

Comment: Do you get error's in the Console? Have you tried to debug your application, there is an debugger built in the browser.

Comment: No errors in the console. I will try using my browser's debugger now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the pot is never actually reduced. You have placed all the code that reduces it inside multiple `setTimeout` calls but they won't be executed until you leave the loop which you will never do because the pot is not reduced!

If you need to use `setTimeout` for your logic, here's how to write the loop:

```
var loopFunction = function() {
        var randomNumber = Math.random() * 4;
        if (randomNumber == 1) {
        }
        ...
        if (potAmount > 0) {
            setTimeout(loopFunction, 3000);
        }
}
```

This way the next iteration will only start after the previous has ended.

Comment: I was actually just thinking about this and your answer confirmed it haha. Thanks! I'll work on rewriting it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your game to continue to run until your `potAmount` runs out, try using a `while()` loop.

```
while(potAmount > 0){
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Browser still freezes and crashes when using while() loop or loop for. (as soon as I confirm settings for the game this happens, the timeout doesn't even run.)

Comment: The `for (; potAmount > 0;)` loop that the OP had is equivalent to a while loop. The real problem is that the potAmount variable is only updated within the function passed to setTimeout, a function that won't run until *after* the loop - so the loop will never end.

Comment: Ahhhh... I understand. Is there anyway to make the loop wait to repeat until each set timeout finishes? (edit, just remembered reading about breaks  in loops, I'll test that out now.)